# Regex to match multiple groups of text

Tags: regex, perl, jmeter

I'm not sure if this is possible in Regex but I want something like...

Input:

```
a="abc1"
...some stuff...
a="def1"
...some stuff...
a="ghi1"
...some stuff...
b="123a"
...some stuff...
a="abc2"
...some stuff...
a="def2"
...some stuff...
a="ghi2"
...some stuff...
b="123b"
...some stuff...
a="abc3"
...some stuff...
a="def3"
...some stuff...
a="ghi3"
...some stuff...
b="123c"
...some stuff...
```

Wants:

```
match_1 = 123a
match_1_1 = abc1
match_1_2 = def1
match_1_3 = ghi1

match_2 = 123b
match_2_1 = abc2
match_2_2 = def2
etc.
```

Attempt:

```
a="([^"]+)"[\D\W\S]+b="([^"]+)"
```

This would get the first "a=abc..." and the "b=123..." of each section but doesn't group "def..." and beyond.

The flavor of regex is the one in JMeter, which I believe is Perl.

Any suggestion or comment is appreciated,
:)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to state, it is the one that JMeter uses. So I believe it is the Perl type.

Comment: When a correct or useful answer is supplied for a question, it is customary to mark that answer as correct (the green outlined checkmark next to the right answer). Please review your three unanswered questions and select an appropriate correct answer where applicable. :)

Comment: @Jared - fml, I thought clicking the up arrow means it is the correct answer. Terribly sorry for those people who answered my questions.

Comment: No problem; many new users don't realize the checkmark's utility. Upvoting is also appreciated, I can tell you. I usually upvote all the good answers, and select the one I think best fits (sometimes this is difficult, so I just have to choose one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this fit your need?

```
(?:a="([^"]+)".*?)(?:a="([^"]+)".*?)(?:a="([^"]+)".*?)b="([^"]+)"
```

You can see it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tul0)

The Groups are in the order as they appear in the input

> Group 1 = abc1
>   Group 2 = def1
>   Group 3 = ghi1
>   Group 4 = 123a

You need to turn on \s (dotall) modifier so that the `.` matches newlines. The `(?:)` are non capturing groups.

Comment: This is good.  I didn't state this, but what if the amount of "a=" are arbitrary while the amount of "b=" stay as single?  So for instance, if there are 5 "a=" on the first group, and 4 "a=" on the second. Is there anyway to group it so that 1 "b=" groups with X "a="?

Comment: I don't know a simple solution and I have only a small idea of a complicated one, don't know if that would work. Its no problem to match what you want, you could use `(?:a="([^"]+)".*?)*b="([^"]+)"` for that but because of the quantifier after the first group, there is always only the last match of the "a=" in the first group. You can see it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tv0q)